# How to rename BI Publisher Report?

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I have developed a new report but I want to rename it, I tried downloading the .xdoz file and opening it and rename contents wherever the title is refered , but its not opening with any editor like notepad++/notedapd etc.

Comment: I have removed all tags related to identity management, as they are not relevant. Oracle BI Publisher Enterprise is under OBIEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of catalog to manage your object. Simply select your object and from "more" select rename to rename your report.

[image]